# JBoss 7.1.1.Final - Load resource from META-INF inside WAR file fails

Tags: java, jboss7.x, wildfly-10

My File is located at:

```
<JBOSS_HOME>/standalone/deployments/mycompany.war/META-INF/myfile.xml
```

The Class which is trying to lookup the file is inside a jar file at:

```
<JBOSS_HOME>/modules/com/mycompany/lib/main/mycompany.jar
```

The code snippet looks like:

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("META-INF/myfile.xml"))
```

This returns null.

Why? I'm lost!

Comment: It seems a problem of classloading isolation. Look at this maybe can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17728385/how-can-i-add-a-jboss-7-1-module-that-contain-classes-that-implements-extends-fr

Comment: Also this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23845031/wildfly-getting-resource-from-war

Comment: @Aris2World, adding <resources><resource-root path="... worked great!. You may add your own answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a problem of classloading isolation. 
Look at this may help [How can i add a jboss 7.1 module that contain classes that implements/extends from classes in the main ear file of the server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17728385/how-can-i-add-a-jboss-7-1-module-that-contain-classes-that-implements-extends-fr)

Specifically try adding below into your jboss-deployment-structure.xml

```
<resources>
    <resource-root path="META-INF/myfolder" /> 
</resources>
```

And access the resources inside it as below.

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(MY_RESOURCE_PATH)
```