# How to load a external jar which has classes that implement an interface within a war deployed in wildfly

Tags: jar, jboss, war, external, wildfly-10

I have a jar that has an implementation class which implements an interface which resides in war. Also jar requires certain custom exceptions and some domain classes from war file.
I can't put the jar into the war, as it can be altered frequently.
I am deploying this war into wildfly 10. I read one post from stackoverflow and tried it [How can i add a jboss 7.1 module that contain classes that implements/extends from classes in the main ear file of the server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17728385/how-can-i-add-a-jboss-7-1-module-that-contain-classes-that-implements-extends-fr), but again I am getting ClassNotFoundException. I put my jar in the standalone folder and give the path for resource in jboss-deployment-structure.xml as

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <resources>
        <resource-root path:"../test.jar"/>
    </resources>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Also I tried doing by referring to it as a module but in turn it needed the dependency from war file which is in different classloader. Can anyone help me with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Since you say you deploy the JAR you should be using a module dependency not a resource dependency.

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="deployment.test.jar"/>
    </dependencies>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

A `<resource/>` is used for file system paths. Have a look at the have a look at the [documentation](http://docs.wildfly.org/13/Developer_Guide.html#jboss-deployment-structure-file) for the `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`.

Comment: I think there may be a slight confusion. I am deploying the WAR file and I want that external jar to be loaded in the same class loader. I already tried adding this JAR as a module in JBOSS and declaring its dependency in jboss-deployment-structure.xml . But the classloader which loads the modules external to WAR is on higher level of the classloader which loads the WAR. So while I try to deploy it said that unable to link that particular external module to WAR, due to dependency of JAR classes on some WAR classes.

Comment: If you want the JAR loaded in the same class loader as the WAR it needs to be included in the WAR. That's the only way that would work.